# Weakly reflexive algebra vs proper (residually finite-dimensional) algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras, duality, coalgebras

Currently I am reading the book "[Hopf Algebras. An Introduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=pBJ6sbPHA0IC)" by S. Dascalescu, C. Nastasescu, S. Raianu. There is a Definition 1.5.20 on page [44](https://books.google.com/books?id=pBJ6sbPHA0IC&pg=PA44) (boldface is mine):

> An algebra $A$ is called **proper** (or **residually finite dimensional**) if $i_A:A \to A^{\circ*}$ is **injective**, it is called **weakly reflexive** if $i_A$ is **injective**, and it is called reflexive if $i_A$ is bijective.

This definition is stated as if being proper and weakly reflexive are two different things, but according to their definition these two concepts are equivalent. I'm wondering if there is a typo in the text. Or the two concepts are actually identical?

Here $A$ is assumed to be a unital, associative algebra over some field $k$.  $$A^\circ = \Big\{ f \in A^* : \exists I : \text{Ideal of} \; A \; \text{such that
} \; I \subset \ker f \; \text{and}\; \dim_k \frac{A}{I} < \infty \Big\}$$ is a finite-dual coalgebra and $i_A$ is a canonical map defined by $i_A(a)(f) = f(a)$. The ideal $I$ in the above definition is assumed to be two-sided.

I don't want to learn wrong definitions, so I will be grateful if somebody more experienced than me can tell me if the definition is correct.

Comment: Do you assume $A$ commutative? could you mention the book's author?

Comment: No I don't assume $A$ to be commutative. However, I assume $A$ to be unital and associative algebra over some field $k$.

Comment: Guessing it’s a typo and that the second “injective” was intended to read “surjective.”

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. I think I can use your guess  as a working hypothesis.

Comment: The relevant page (which I have also edited into the post):  https://books.google.com/books?id=pBJ6sbPHA0IC&pg=PA44 .